# delete messages after banning

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am working on a ban command. I successfullly ban the person, but the problem is the messages he has written doesnt get deleted. So is there a way to implement this? Like delete a messages a particular member before 14 days?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Ban member from the server. Permissions applied.',
    usage:  '<Username | UserID> <reason>',
    cooldown: 1,
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(client, message, args) {
        let target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
        if (!target) return message.channel.send('Please mention a user to be banned!')

        let reason;
        let arg = message.content.split(' ').slice(2);

        if (arg.length == 0) {
            reason = 'No reason specified.'
        }
        else {
            reason = arg.join(' ')
        }

        if(!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the permission to use this command!');
        if(target.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send('You cannot ban yourself!');
        if(target.user.bot) return message.channel.send('Sorry we dont ban other bots. Please do so manually!')
        if(target.permissions.has('MUTE_MEMBERS') && message.member != message.guild.owner) return message.channel.send('You have not BAN_MEMBERS permissions')
        if(!message.guild.member(target).bannable) return message.channel.send("Sorry cant ban that user!");

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('You have been **banned!**')
        .addField('Server Name: ', `**${message.guild.name}**`)
        .addField('Banned by:', `**${message.author.username}**`)
        .addField('Reason: ', `**${reason}**`)
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL()}`)
        .setTimestamp()

        message.delete()

        target.send(embed).then(() => {
            message.channel.send(`${target.user.tag} has been banned!`)
        }).then(() => {
                message.guild.member(target).ban({days: 7})//message.channel.send(`${member.user.tag} has been kicked!`)
            })

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it even banning the member? From what I see, it shouldn't even ban them, given your code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options in [`GuildMember#ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) is the number of days of messages to delete (between 0 and 7)

So you can use:

```js
message.guild.member(target).ban({ days: 4 })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

For example.